# How to get the jCanvas version?

Tags: jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, jcanvas

The Doc says the $.jCanvas object has the 'version' property, but alert($.jCanvas.version) says 'undefined'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Caleb531 just [fixed the documentation](https://github.com/caleb531/jcanvas/issues/46) so that future users will avoid the confusion @lxmfly123 expressed.

UPDATE (2013-01-25):  @Caleb531 now builds jCanvas with [build.py](https://github.com/caleb531/jcanvas/blob/master/build/build.py), which auto-generates a "YY.MM.DD" version in [jcanvas.js](https://github.com/caleb531/jcanvas/blob/master/jcanvas.js) and [jcanvas.jquery.json](https://github.com/caleb531/jcanvas/blob/master/jcanvas.jquery.json).

Answer (score 4):

That is simple and fun:

[That commit](https://github.com/caleb531/jcanvas/commit/b21ac2fff0281445816b875bed68bbdbdcc9a56c#diff-31) has a comment: **Removed the version number from jCanvas for the sake of simplicity.**

4 days ago